# React Router's useParams cause useEffect to rerun

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am using `react-router` 5.1 and `react` 16.10.

For a Master-Detail page, I am using `useParams()` to get the id from the url to open the page for the current group. Opening happens in a `useEffect()`. As a result, `id` has to be given as a dependency in that effect. However, when creating a new group, when there is enough data for a group to be valid, the API sends the `id` for that group and it sets the URL to `/group/:id`. As a result however, the effect runs again.

```js
function Groups(props) {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const history = useHistory();

  const [group, setGroup] = useState(NEW_GROUP);

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    await Promise.resolve(Api.getGroups());
  }, []);

  const getGroup = useCallback(async group => {
    history.push(`/groups/${group.id}`);

    await Promise.resolve(Api.getGroup(group)).then(data => {
      setGroup(data.group);
    });
  }, [getData, history]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();

    if (id !== undefined) {
      getGroup({ id });
    }
  }, [props.actions, id, getData, getGroup]);

  // Saving data
  const saveGroup = useCallback(async () => {
    setSaved(SAVING);

    await Promise.resolve(Api.storeGroup(group)).then(data => {
        if (!group.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            history.push(`/groups/${data.id}`);
            setGroup(prevGroup => ({ ...prevGroup, id: data.id }));
        }

        getData();
        setSaved(SAVED);
    }).catch(() => setSaved(FAILED));
  }, [getData, group, history]);
}
```

How do I prevent this from happening without breaking the "rules of hooks"?

Comment: Do you want that the useEffects runs only when id value change?

Comment: I only want it to run the first time. Normally that would be done with leaving the dependency array empty, but that is in this case a violation of the "rules of hooks" and I rather not include a rule exception for ESlin.

Comment: @Yannick Did you ever solve this? I have the exact same issue, using useParams() for an object id which causes useEffect to infinitely loop.

Comment: I have not found a proper solution for this, we simply don't change the URL at this point. It is less than ideal, though.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, and the way I solved is by passing the id from useParams to the function and set id only in useEffect.

```
function Groups(props) {
  const { id } = useParams();
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(id);

    if (id !== undefined) {
      getGroup({ id });
    }
  }, [id]);

 ...
}
```

Comment: it works for me , i used getGroup( id) instead of getGroup({ id });

Comment: Same in"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0", I wonder why useEffect sees id is changed when id is keep undefined. Seems something is in the useParams()...